# Break Point on File Modification or on File Open

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2005, filesystems

I would like to set a break point on file modification for a particular file, or on opening a particular file. This is a file which our software opens and modifies during portions of legacy code. I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem. One approach I have thought about was to find all of the places where we are opening files, break on all of them, and inspect the file path to determine if it is the path we are concerned with. The other approach I was thinking was to attempt to set a break point in the file system opening code when the path matches what I am concerned with (possibly more difficult, as I am presently running under Windows. This might be an option under Linux but a Visual Studio 2005 solution would be ideal and a Linux solution potentially useful).

Presently, I am using Visual Studio 2005 for my software project in C++. I was not able to find anything online about this as an option or an approach people would like to take.

Normally, I would say that I should just understand where this file is being opened. Unfortunately this section of code is quite difficult to understand and will be re-factored, but for the immediate future this functionality would help me.

Thank you very much for reading my question,

-Brian J. Stinar-

Comment: I am not 100% sure if the following is possible with VS2005 (with 08 and 10 it is), but anyways: It is possible to make a breakpoint "triggering" a break when some special condition is hit (e.g. when an counter in a for-loop hits some wanted value, so the loop is suspended in its n-th loop)... hope i could explain it somehow understandable with my english :D...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put conditional breakpoint to kernel32.CreateFileW and check file name.
Then you will get file handle, so you can put conditional breakpoint to kernel32.CreateFileW and check file handle.

Also you can hook CreateFileW and call __debugbreak() in it.

Comment: I understand what you're talking about at a conceptual level, but I'm not exactly sure how to put that kernel32.CreateFileW break point in. Do you have any additional information on that? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Brian Stinar: just add it manually in breapoints window, use "CreateFileW" as function name.